# Having trouble with gradient editor

Tags: html, css

I'm using this gradient editor: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

But instead of displaying a smooth background like displayed, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuaC5.png

I've tried setting background-repeat:repeat-y and x but it doesn't seem to help!

Comment: Do not downvote my post with no reason given!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need it to be an `<img>` or not, if not, you could make it a `<div>` and use the exact code which generated the gradient you saw on the mentioned tool.

```
<div style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;background: background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 63%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(63%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */; /* FF3.6+ */;" width="713" height="300"></div>
```

instead of:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ktk7fR7.png" width="713" height="300">
```

to be specific. I am not sure how to get it to work with an `<img>`.

Example of code placing the gradient background on the body-tag to have a full-page gradient background:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>pcfOTC7.png (1312×602)</title>
    </head>

    <body style="position:absolute; margin: 0px;background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */ background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 63%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(63%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */ background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 63%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand. I've made it a div, but I'm not sure where exactly to place the div. If I place it inside the body, then only the stuff in my container gets the background. If I place it around the body then nothing changes.

Comment: do you want the gradient in the background filling all of the background? In that case you could put it on the `<body>` tag itself.

Comment: That works better except now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/pcfOTC7.png

I was hoping to make it look like in the example on the gradient editor where it's smooth all the way.

Comment: I might just be misunderstanding what you want to do I will add to my answer the code I am running so you can try it out and see if it is what you are looking fore and we can take it from there..

Comment: I want my whole background to look like the example in the generator:

http://i.imgur.com/gzgu6DN.png

Comment: Look at my output: http://jsfiddle.net/g2ZmM/

Ignore the .bk css element. I detached it and put it directly to style like you did.

Comment: hmm... from the look of it I'd say the height of body is not getting evaluated correct.. if you were to set the `position` of `<body>` to `absolute` I guess it should work. Might also need to specify the `height` or even `min-height` to be `100%` but I believe it shouldn't be needed. I updated the answer to reflect this.